# Usage of ";" . Can it connect verb phrases without conjunctions?

Tags: conjunctions, semicolons

I know ";" can connect related sentences without any conjunctions.
Now I wonder if  ";" can also connect verb phrases as follow:

The device calculates ....; selects ....; programs....; and changes... .

Thank you for your kind advice in advance.

Regards,

Comment: Is there potentially ambiguous internal punctuation in the items being connected using semicolons? If so, then sure. If not, then why not simply use commas.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. There are many commas in each verb phrase; simply they are quite long. I am trying to include all of the verb phrases in one sentence. That is why I want to know if this usage is grammatically correct, or not. Regards, Hiro

Answer (score 1):

The usage of punctuation marks is not an issue of grammar, but rather one of style.  As such, you should be guided by your manual of style -- either the one you've selected if you're writing for yourself or the one thrust upon you by the person for whom or institution for which you are writing.  I use the *Chicago Manual of Style*, which suggests two circumstances of interest:

> If the **clauses of a compound sentence** are very long or are themselves
>   subdivided by commas, a semicolon may be used between them even if
>   they are jointed by a conjunction.

and

> When **items in a series** are long and complex or involve internal
>   punctuation, they should be separated by semicolons for the sake of
>   clarity....

Comment: If it is a matter of style, what important is to use the style throughout the article.